# passing array values in bulk to code behind using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, arrays, ajax

i need to pass values to code behind from client side to server side how can i do this

Comment: Do you have any webmethod as name `Done` in your cs file?

Answer (score 0):

The data send generally needs to be a key value pair. I don't think simply sending a string would work. The data variable generally needs to be an array of object, with each object having two keys: **name** and **value**
I usually have two ways of doing this

**Method 1:**
This method serializes the whole array into one string (similar to what you are trying) and sends it across. A big disadvantage of this is that if the array is too long it sends a really long string which may cross the limit (the limit then needs to be increased from web config). A big advantage of this however is you could directly serialize the object into a c# object.

The way is to change your line `data: JSON.stringify({ arr: values })` into `data: [{name:"values", value:JSON.stringify(values)}]` and then access the *values* string in c# and deserialize it. 
In c# you need to have a code something like this:

> JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();   MyObject
>   object = js.Deserialize(Request.Params('values'));

You now have an object of type MyObject that you could use. Note that in order to be able to use this, you will need the c# object and js object to be of the exact same format. Note that in this case the MyObject would be an array of something so it needs to be replaced with something like this:  `object = js.Deserialize<string[]>(Request.Params('values'))`

**Method 2:**
This method can take each js item in the array as a separate item and send it across. In the js code, add `var i = 0;` before the *$.ajax({* line. Then replace `data: JSON.stringify({ arr: values })` with `data: values.map(v => ({name: i++, value: v}))`.

Now in your c# code, you can acess each element of the array as `Request.Params("0")`, `Request.Params("1")` and so on...

Comment: yes the older code din't contain everything and was also wrong... i have updated it. I wasn't sure what type of data exactly you are trying to send. 
The first type uses the stringify function you tried to use properly. The second function is more recommended if you are simply sending an int array and you are not sure of the size.

Comment: can you please modify and show it in my code i want to pass bulk array values to code behind either they may be of integer type or string type using ajax

Comment: if the data will only be an integer or string, you could use method 1 for less confusion. I have mentioned above what goes in the jquery part (a small modification) and what goes in the c# part